# Swift: How can I store array data, so it can be accessed more than once after leaving class?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm currently trying to develop a prototype for a quiz application.

The questions for the quiz are read out of a JSON file and the answers are generated within the program. Those two parts are then matched to each other within a Mediator class.

Displaying the question in my ViewController works perfectly fine for the first question. When trying to retrieve the second question the array that stores the question in the Mediator class is empty. That obviously is the case, because I'm re-entering the Mediator after going to my ViewController.

How can I store the data more efficiently?

If you need more information, please let me know. I'm really grateful for every suggestion I can get. I'm totally stuck at right now!

#### ViewController:

[...]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup(categoryType)
    navigationBar.title = barTitle
    QAMatcher.delegate = self
    QAMatcher.getCategory(categoryType)
}

 @objc func didChooseAnswer(_ sender: UIButton){
    QAMatcher.nextQuestion()
    updateUI()
}

func updateUI(){
    if let label = questionLabel {
        label.text = QAMatcher.getQuestion()
    }
    if let type = AnswerType(rawValue: QAMatcher.getAnswerType()) {
        addAnswerSection(type)
    }
}

func addAnswerSection(_ type: AnswerType) {
    if let stackView = quizStackView, let answerSection = uiBuilder.getAnswerSection(answerType: type) {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(answerSection)
    }
}
```

[...]

#### Mediator Class:

```
import Foundation

protocol Mediator {
func sendRequest (_ request: Request, sender: Sender)
```

}

```
protocol MediatorDelegate {
func didUpdate(mediator: QuestionAnswerMediator, _ array: [QuestionData])
```

}

```
enum Sender {
case answer
case question
```

}

```
class QuestionAnswerMediator: Mediator {

var delegate: MediatorDelegate?
var questionArray = [QuestionData]()
var answerArray = [String]()

var request = Request()
var questionNum = 0

func getCategory(_ category: CategoryType) {
    request.categoryType = category
    matchQuestionAndAnswers()
}

func sendRequest (_ request: Request, sender: Sender){
    if sender == .question {
        let array = QuestionManager.shared.send(category: request.categoryType!)
        questionArray.append(contentsOf: array)
    }
    else if sender == .answer {
        let array = AnswerManager.shared.send(request: request)
        if array?.isEmpty == false {
            answerArray = []
            answerArray.append(contentsOf: array ?? ["default"])
        }
    }
}

func fetchAnswers(for type: String, question: String) {
    request.answerType = AnswerType(rawValue: type)
    request.question = question
    sendRequest(request, sender: .answer)
}

func fetchQuestions (for category: CategoryType){
    request.categoryType = category
    sendRequest(request, sender: .question)
}

func matchQuestionAndAnswers(){
    var i = 0
    fetchQuestions(for: request.categoryType!)
    for question in questionArray {
        fetchAnswers(for: question.answerType, question: question.question)
        if answerArray.isEmpty != true {
            questionArray[i].answers = answerArray
        }
        i += 1
    }
    self.delegate?.didUpdate(mediator: self, questionArray)
}

func getQuestion() -> String {
    return questionArray[questionNum].question
}

func getAnswers() -> [String] {
    return questionArray[questionNum].answers!
}

func getAnswerType() -> String {
     return questionArray[questionNum].answerType
}

func nextQuestion () {
    if questionNum + 1 < questionArray.count {
        questionNum += 1
    }
    else {
        questionNum = 0
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] as text using proper code formatting instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: don't use screenshots to show us code, we cannot copy it, we cannot read it in a good way...

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the tip! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: thx for improving your question....unfortunately we cannot copy and use it, because it is not a reproducable example. there is missing a lot of code. so please...give us a link to your github project or minimize the code to a very small project which you can completely copied in here.

Comment: https://github.com/vayvy/quiz-application

Comment: @Chris I now added the project to GitHub :)

Comment: great! unfortunately you did not insert your project file in it...just the soures ;) this file ends with .xcodeproj

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry for all the mistakes! I thought I also uploaded the project file. :( I added it now. Hopefully, everything will work now. Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: it is still not in there...could you please check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, that was hard ;) i had to create my own project file, because yours was still missing. After doing that i tried to compile and run...but you did not fill the assets so it crashed. After faking your assets...it runs. ;)

You already analyzed your problem correctly. You should never create a viewcontroller mutliple times if you just call him once. So i deleted this and you now only have one instance.
i routed the "didchooseAnswer" through your classes...but you still have some work to do: i had to give a frame to your view class, so fill that frame you need, i don't know what frame you need.

I just corrected it for MultipleChoiceView...you have to do it for the other views as well like PolarView etc...

i hope i have everything copied what i changed, if not, just tell me. but maybe then you should give me rights on your github project so that i can commit it there...

Quizviewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import os

class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationItem!

    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var quizStackView: UIStackView!

    var barTitle: String?

    //variables for location services
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationData: LocationModel?

    //variables for communication with Mediator
    var QAMatcher = QuestionAnswerMediator()
    var questions : [QuestionData]?
    var categoryType: CategoryType!
    var timer = Timer()

    //Change UI depending on answer type
    var uiBuilder = AnswerViewBuilder()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup(categoryType)
        navigationBar.title = barTitle
        QAMatcher.delegate = self
        QAMatcher.getCategory(categoryType)
    }

    @objc func didChooseAnswer(_ sender: UIButton){
        QAMatcher.nextQuestion()
        updateUI()
    }
}

//MARK: - Setup & updating UI

extension QuizViewController: MediatorDelegate {

    func didUpdate(mediator: QuestionAnswerMediator, _: [QuestionData]) {
        self.updateUI()
    }


    func setup(_ category: CategoryType?) {
        switch category {
        case .shortterm:
            print("No function yet")
        case .longterm:
            print("No function yet")
        case .problemsolving:
            print("No function yet")
        case .orientation:
            locationManager.delegate = self
            checkLocationServiceSupport()
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            gecodeCurrentLocation()
        default:
            let message: StaticString = M.Errors.invalidCategoryError
            os_log(message, log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
        }
    }

    func updateUI(){
        if let label = questionLabel {
            label.text = QAMatcher.getQuestion()
        }
        if let type = AnswerType(rawValue: QAMatcher.getAnswerType()) {
            addAnswerSection(type)
        }
    }

    func addAnswerSection(_ type: AnswerType) {
        if let stackView = quizStackView, let answerSection = uiBuilder.getAnswerSection(answerType: type, didChooseAnswer: self.didChooseAnswer(_:)) {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(answerSection)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension QuizViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        let message: StaticString = M.Errors.locationDetectionError
        os_log(message, log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }

    func checkLocationServiceSupport () {
        if CLLocationManager.significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable() != true {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: M.Alters.locationAlertTitle, message: M.Alters.locationAlert, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                NSLog("The user acknowledge that location services are not available.")
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func gecodeCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        if let lastLocation = self.locationManager.location {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(lastLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        let city = placemark.locality!
                        let country = placemark.country!
                        self.locationData = LocationModel(city: city,country: country)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let message: StaticString = M.Errors.locationDecodingError
                    os_log(message, log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



//MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
//extension CategoryViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
//
//    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
//        if textField.text != "" {
//            return true
//        }
//        else {
//            textField.placeholder = "Enter your answer here"
//            return false
//        }
//    }
//
//    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
//    }
//
//     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
//        textField.endEditing(true)
//        return true
//        }
//}
```

MulitpleChoiceView

```
import UIKit

class MultipleChoiceView: UIStackView {
    var button1 = UIButton()
    var button2 = UIButton()
    var button3 = UIButton()

    var didChooseAnswer : ((UIButton)->())?

    init(frame: CGRect, didChooseAnswer: @escaping (UIButton)->()) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.didChooseAnswer = didChooseAnswer
        self.addAnswerView()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addAnswerView() {
        setupStackView()
        costumeButtons()
    }

    func setupStackView() {
        self.alignment = .fill
        self.distribution = .fillEqually
        self.spacing = 10
        self.axis = .vertical
    }

    func costumeButtons() {
        let buttons = [button1 , button2, button3]
        let dimensions = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 20)
        let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7294117647, green: 0.7450980392, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        for button in buttons {
            button.frame = dimensions
            button.backgroundColor = color
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height / 4
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: M.Selector.buttonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
            self.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }

    @objc func didChooseAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let didChooseAnswer = didChooseAnswer {
            didChooseAnswer(sender)
        }
    }
}
```

AnswerViewBuilder

import UIKit

```
class AnswerViewBuilder {
    func getAnswerSection(answerType: AnswerType, didChooseAnswer: @escaping (UIButton)->()) -> UIView?{
        switch (answerType) {
        case .multipleChoice:
            return MultipleChoiceView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), didChooseAnswer: didChooseAnswer)
        case .textField:
            return TextFieldView()
        case .polarQuestion:
            return PolarQuestionView()
        case .ranking:
            return MultipleChoiceView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), didChooseAnswer: didChooseAnswer)
        default:
            print("Answer section could not be created.")
            return nil
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I'm really sorry for making it so difficult for you! I really appreciate your help! I will try to implement your approach to the project!

Comment: you are welcome. would be nice if you could check my answer as "right answer" ;)

Comment: I changed my code according to your answer. Now the new answerView is added to the main view. :) However, the previously added subviews also remain.

Comment: The problem is solved I added a new function that removes the last element from the array arrangedSubviews before adding the new answer section. :)